# Multiway map in C++

Tags: c++, hash-map

I recently had the problem that I wanted a hashmap where there would be a variable amount of distinct classes which each could be used to look up each other. I couldn't find any implementation online so I wrote it myself:

```
// Compile with c++20 because this code uses concepts
#include <concepts>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <tuple>

template <typename T> concept Streamable = requires(std::ostream &os, T value) {
    { os << value } -> std::convertible_to<std::ostream &>;
};

template<typename T> concept nMapValidType = std::default_initializable<T> && std::equality_comparable<T> && Streamable<T>;

template<nMapValidType ...T>
class nMap {
    public:
    nMap(std::initializer_list<std::tuple<T...>> iList) : 
        vec(iList) {}

    ~nMap() = default;

    void add(std::tuple<T...> tuple) {
        this->vec.push_back(tuple);
    }

    nMap<T...>& operator=(std::initializer_list<std::tuple<T...>> iList) {
        this->vec = iList;
        return *this;
    }

    template<nMapValidType Gettee, nMapValidType Getter>
    Gettee get(Getter getVal, bool throwError = true) const {
        if constexpr (!std::disjunction_v<std::is_same<Gettee, T>...>) {
            std::perror("Return type for nMap::get not found.");
        } else {}
        if constexpr (!std::disjunction_v<std::is_same<Getter, T>...>) {
            std::perror("Getter type for nMap::get not found.");
        } else {}

        for (const auto& tuple: this->vec) {
            if (std::get<Getter>(tuple) == getVal) {
                return std::get<Gettee>(tuple);
            }
        }

        if (throwError) {
            std::stringstream sstr;
            sstr << "No keys to value `" << getVal << "` found.";
            std::perror(sstr.str().c_str());
        }
        return {};
    }

    template<nMapValidType Type>
    bool contains(Type item) const {
        if constexpr (!std::disjunction_v<std::is_same<Type, T>...>) {
            std::perror("Type passed to nMap::contains not found.");
        } else {}
        for (const auto &tuple: this->vec) {
            if (std::get<Type>(tuple) == item) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private:
    std::vector<std::tuple<T...>> vec;
};

template<nMapValidType A, nMapValidType B, nMapValidType C>
using triMap = nMap<A, B, C>;

template<nMapValidType A, nMapValidType B>
using biMap = nMap<A, B>;


int main() {
    const nMap<int, char, bool> boolMap = {
        { 0, 'f', false},
        { 1, 't', true}
    };
    bool testBool = boolMap.get<bool>('f');
    int testInt = boolMap.get<int, bool>(true);
    return testInt;
}
```

While functioning quite well, I feel that the lookup for both `get` and `contains` could be improved.

Another feature that this implementation is missing, is both the `get` and `contains` function. I haven't had a use for non-const `nMap`'s yet, so this is not a dealbreaker but I just don't want to copy-paste those huge chunks of code.

Something that I feel is impossible is the separation of declaration and definition of these functions, as they are included in many files in a larger project I'm working on and compile-times have proven to be quite slow (I don't know if it is because of this class, this just may be a factor).

Answer (score 4):

## Don't call this a map

Your `nMap` is just presenting a convenient API for a `std::vector<std::tuple<...>>`, however it has almost none of the properties of an STL map. Someone familiar with the STL but now with the implementation details of your class will be confused, and think for example that objects stored in the map can be retrieved in \$O(\log N)\$ time and have stable pointers, when that is not the case.

## Try to match the API of STL containers as much as possible

A container becomes much more useful if its API closely matches that of other STL containers. For one, it makes it much easier for programmers: they don't have to remember two different APIs. The other reason is that generic [algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) will be able to work with your container if it has the expected API.

For `get()`, that might be problematic, as it's a combination of `std::tuple`'s `get()` and the `std::find()` algorithm. But `add()` could be renamed to `push_back()` at least.

There is also a lot missing that would be useful, like iterators, `operator[]`, `clear()`, `resize()` and so on.

## What if you have identical types?

What if you want to have a `nMap<int, int, int>`? You can create one and add elements, but you can't use `get()` or `contains()` with it.

## Think about references and non-`const` access

Your `get()` makes a copy of a value stored in the map. For large types, this can be inefficient. Consider returning a (`const`) reference to the gettee.

Also think about how you pass parameters: `getVal` should be a `const` reference, `add()` should also take a `const` reference, and/or an rvalue reference.

## `throw` instead of using `perror()`

`perror()` is a C function. In C++, prefer to `throw` errors: this allows the caller to `catch` them and do something about it, if so desired.

Also, for compile-time errors, use `static_assert()`: this will cause the compilation to abort, so the programmer can find problems early. Compiling in a call to `perror()` might delay discovery of a programming error until the program is run.

Also, don't try to print the value you cannot find if this restricts the types your class can support.

Comment: Thank you for the insight! The main gripe with it is the section about errors. There is nothing unexpected about the errors, I find it to be better to actually check if the `nMap` actually `contains` the element and only then `get` it, but that is just my personal opinion. And also I did use `static_assert`, just not in one place where it was "impossible" because checking if the nMap contains an element can only be done at run-time.

Comment: I don't see any `static_assert()` in your code. Of course, if it's only something that can be done at runtime, then indeed you cannot use it. Have a look at how the STL handles this in [`std::map::at()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at).

Comment: I changed the code in my editor and then forgot to paste the changes over. My mistake. Every error in the original question except for the one in `get` now uses `static_assert`. You also mentioned the Big-O of the lookup, which I believe to currently be \$O(N)\$. Do you think this could be improved?

Comment: Sure, you can use multiple `std::map`s or `std::unordered_map`s instead of single `std::vector` to allow for fast lookups. This will complicate the code and increase memory usage of course, but that might be a perfectly fine trade-off if you expect to do a lot of lookups.

Comment: How would that work with the typepack though?

Comment: You'd have to use some tricks. Consider that instead of a vector of tuples, you can make a tuple of vectors: `std::tuple<std::vector<T>, ...> vecs`. This allows you to create multiple container objects given a type pack. How to turn this into multiple maps is more complicated, you'd first have to think of how you want to organize your data. First, think of how you would write a `triMap` by hand using `std::map`s, then when that works, try to turn it into a variadic template.